# Assistance with Google Drive sample demo needed

Tags: android

Being totally new to Java, Android Dev and Android Studio - I am struggling somewhat.

I want to create an app where I can pick a folder in Google Drive.  Look at the photos in that folder and select whichever photos I wish (multi select).

I then want to get the Drive metadata for those photos - e.g. the link to the photo, and be able to loop through each photo and execute another activity (e.g. send those photos in an email for example).

Here is the sample demo:

https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/PickFolderWithOpenerActivity.java

I am using the PickFolderWithOpenerActivity as the first activity, which allows me to select a folder (the folder contents are greyed out though).

When I select a folder, it this populates the folder driveId (from sample):

```
 showMessage("Selected folder's ID: " + driveId);
```

Next - I assume I need to call another Activity, e.g. ListFilesInFolderActivity.java.

I assume this activity needs to be called using an intent.

Questions:

1. How do I pass the driveId to the ListFilesInFolderActivity?
2. Assuming the above works, how do I make the files (multi) selectable?

In the BaseActivity.java - there is a static String:

```
public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "0B2EEtIjPUdX6MERsWlYxN3J6RU0";
```

So in the PickFolderActvity, I tried to override this, using the following:

```
           showMessage("Selected folder's ID: " + driveId);
           EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = driveId.toString();

           Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFilesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

But the application just crashes.
Note that I cannot seem to use an emulator, something to do with Google Play services.  I am having to generate an apk and transfer to my device.

Thanks for any help here, and I appreciate any patience for a beginner.

Here is the code from the PickFolderWithOpenerActivity, [EDIT] I have modified the code and it now works and the ListFilesInFolder.java is called.  But the files are not listed in the ListView.  I'm not sure why.:

```
public class PickFolderWithOpenerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "PickFolderWithOpenerActivity";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 1;

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[] { DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE })
                .build(getGoogleApiClient());
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                    showMessage("Selected folder's ID: " + driveId);
                    EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = driveId.getResourceId();

               Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFilesInFolderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                }
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the driveID is wrong, it is the driveID.resourceID that is needed to get the folder.  I have changed the code as follows EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = driveId.getResourceId();

                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFilesInFolderActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);                                               It is now working and going to the ListFilesinFolder.java, but it is not displaying any files in the ListView... any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when I was passing the driveID to the ListFilesInFolder.java, it was incorrect.

I should have instead been passing the resourceID.

Here is the corrected code from the PickFolderWithOpenerActivity.java:

```
EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = driveId.getResourceId();

               Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFilesInFolderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

This now works and the code calls the ListFilesInFolderActivity.  But it does not list the files in the ListView.  I'll open a separate question for that!